# Copying a whole system from an sd card to another

Tags: linux, sd-card

I am copying an OS from one SD card to another, and trying to boot it up.

The original SD card was bootable from the pi without trouble.

Particularly, I understand there may be conflict with the partitions, because I am not creating any, but it would be great if you explain whether this would fail, and why.

(I have tried and so far it fails)

Comment: "_I have tried and so far it fails_" - I'd suggest you've done something wrong or missed something critical... Rather than asking a hugely open question ("_Why might it fail?_"), could you share the steps you've taken, and tell us what actually happens in more detail than "_it fails_"?

Comment: @Attie i supposed there was some obvious mistake in the idea. Well the pi won't boot and tells 'card detected. not a FAT system'

Comment: How did you copy the partitions?

Comment: I just run `cp sourceSD destSD` @gronostaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying files from a logical partition to another does not make the target device bootable.

If you want to clone a card, clone the whole device, not just files on a logical partition. For example "dd" tool can be used, or likely there are tools to make bootable Raspberry Pi cards.

Comment: That's smart. I will use `dd`. Can you explain **why** cp would not work, as it is exactly the same stuff that was running at a different card?

Comment: But it isn't the same stuff. You can use cp to copy files from file system to another file system. But cp will only copy files. It won't copy other areas of file system (partition boot sector) or areas outside of file systems (master boot sector) that are needed for a card to be bootable.

Comment: ok. thank you for explaining to me